# How to make group of same elements in list using scala?

Tags: scala

Assuming we have a case class Student

```
case class Student(name: String,roll: String)
```

and a list of Student

```
List(Student("a","123"),Student("b","345"),Student("a","678"),Student("b","321"))
```

I want to make groups with same name like

```
List(Student("a","123"),Student("a","678")) , List(Student("b","345"),Student("b","321"))
```

how can I do this using scala?

Comment: Are you looking for a `Map`? Where key represents your group and the value is a `List` of `Students`

Comment: @RP- No. I want list of list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
case class Student(name: String,roll: String)

val list = List(Student("a","123"),Student("b","345"),Student("a","678"),Student("b","321"))

val groupedList = list.groupBy(_.name).values.toList
// groupedList: List[List[Student]] = List(
//   List(Student(b,345), Student(b,321)), List(Student(a,123), Student(a,678))
// )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a `List[List[Student]]` then you need to group `Student`s into Lists

```
val groups = List( List(Student("a","123"),Student("a","678")), List(Student("b","345"),Student("b","321")) )
```

If you are looking for `Map[String, List[Student]]`

```
val groups = Map("a" -> List(Student("a","123"),Student("a","678")), "b" -> List(Student("b","345"),Student("b","321")))
```

Comment: I have List(Student("a","123"),Student("b","345"),Student("a","678"),Student("b","321")) but how to do like List( List(Student("a","123"),Student("a","678")), List(Student("b","345"),Student("b","321")) )

Comment: Okay, I got you now, you already have a `List` ready and want to convert to `List[List]`. Then `groupBy` should work as Luca and Leo suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `groupBy`on the list and then extract the values

```
scala> case class Student(name: String,roll: String)
defined class Student

scala> val l = List(Student("a","123"),Student("b","345"),Student("a","678"),Student("b","321"))
l: List[Student] = List(Student(a,123), Student(b,345), Student(a,678), Student(b,321))

scala> l.groupBy(_.name).values.toList
res0: List[List[Student]] = List(List(Student(b,345), Student(b,321)), List(Student(a,123), Student(a,678)))
```